# OpenVPN connects but no data with OpenVPN server .... sometimes

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I have OpenVPN server running on Ubuntu server (16.04.2) on Digital Ocean. I have had this server running for quite awhile. It works without any issues that I am able to tell.

1) I have an Ubuntu client. This computer always connects to the server without any issue either by using the Unity OpenVPN connector thingy on the top menu bar or by using the .ovpn file directly.

2) I have an Android mobile client which is using Open VPN client and it is always connected to the same server.

3) I have a Windows client that I use periodically. It never has trouble connecting to the server.

The problem is periodically with #1 above: the Ubuntu client. As I said, it always connects without issue. But there are times that 0 byes flow either way while it is connected and regardless of how it is connected. When it is in this “mood”, rebooting or reconnecting doesn't solve the problem. It will be like this for a day or so and then it will just work fine for weeks before pulling this little number on me again.

All devices are on the same WiFi and during these fugues, only the Ubuntu client is affected. When it is affected, net commands are dreadfully slow (e.g. ‘route’).

When it **is working**, route returns:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.0.5       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
10.10.0.1       10.10.0.5       255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.10.0.5       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.10.0.5       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
[servers name]  gateway         255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlp3s0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 docker0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
```

When it **is not working**, route returns (albeit very slowly):

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.10.0.5       0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 tun0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
10.10.0.1       10.10.0.5       255.255.255.255 UGH   50     0        0 tun0
10.10.0.5       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    50     0        0 tun0
[server’s name] 192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlp3s0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 docker0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
```

Why this behavior? I do not know and have not been able to find any information. Again: same server across several clients. The Android client is persistently connected and it never has any issues. The Windows client: it runs as a Vbox guest on the same Ubuntu client that has issues. If it is having issues, then I don’t connect it to the VPN but the Winows Vbox client on that same machine has no issue connecting and no issues moving bytes back and forth.

Client’s .ovpn (same for all clients):

```
client
dev tun
mssfix 1200
proto udp
remote vpn.myserver.com 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
pkcs12 mykey.p12
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo
verb 3
auth-user-pass
```

Again, authenticating and connecting is not an issue ever. MTU size is critical: MTU auto-discovery is not reliable anywhere and some “coffee shops” or routers on the cloud in between the client and the server have issues if MTU size isn’t reduced because then the actual packet size will sometimes exceed the maximum and cause issues. But, as I said, the only client having the issue is the Ubuntu client. Same config works everywhere else.

I have also tried with various other configurations (client & server): TCP instead of UDP; different port numbers.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `route returns (albeit very slowly):` - If your route table is being displayed slowly, then you may have a **DNS problem**.  the route command attempts to resolve the nets to names.  When it is happening try `route -n`  If/when that makes your route table print nice and fast, then fix your DNS.

Comment: @Zoredache This definitely points me into a clearer direction. The last thing on my mind was an issue with DNS. Curious as to why a DNS issue would *only* manifest while connected to VPN (and only for a single client that, otherwise, has no apparent DNS problems)?

Comment: I don't have enough information to guess at why it is a problem, or where your problem is yet.  All I know is that seems very much like a DNS symptom.  Either you can't reach the DNS configured server, or something else.